# Need help for package magento connect extensions

Tags: magento-1.8

I was reading this below article to create package from magento connect.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_modules_and_development/creating_magento_connect_extension_package

But I am confused at two points in this article.

First how can I find Dependencies for magento extention.

Second is that, one look on this image
[http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/*detail/general/contents2.jpg?id=7*-_modules_and_development%3Acreating_magento_connect_extension_package&cache=cache](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/_detail/general/contents2.jpg?id=7_-_modules_and_development%3Acreating_magento_connect_extension_package&cache=cache)

According to this article

```
Magento Community module file - ./app/code/community
```

And in the image they have used

Magento Community module file - Bloghome

"Bloghome" seems to be module directory than it is okay.

```
Magento User Interface (layouts, templates) - ./app/design
```

In the image they have used..

Magento User Interface (layouts, templates) - adminhtml/default/default/layout/bloghome_blog.xml

this also seems okay because this is layout xml file which is in /app/design directory

```
 Magento Local module file - ./app/code/local
```

But in the image they have used

Magento Local module file - frontend/base/default/layout/bloghome_blog.xml

Here 'Magento Local module file' is consider to be '/app/code/local' but here path is for '/app/design'. That is the point where I am confused.

Please guide why they have used 'Magento Local module file' for app/design layout xml file.

thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Dependencies - you have to know what additional library is using your module if using some. If your module is making connection with curl then you have to add curl dependency and so on. This is for Extensions. About Packages you can add Mage_Core_Modules and to specify Magento versions for which you tested your module. For PHP Version - if you used some specific things that are deprecated in the new versions you have to specify some older versions or the opposite - if you used some new features - you have to specify newer versions. If you are not sure which versions to fill in - you can use these from the example (I think they are okay most of the cases).

About the image/screenshot - it's wrong. For these files it should be Magento User Interface. Don't look at the image, read what is written.

Comment: Thanks for replay. After all these steps I saved the form and it given me message that `The package module_name data has been loaded.` But I can't find where package has been saved. I have searched each directory of the magento project, but not found anywhere. Do you have any why data has not been saved

Comment: You have to click "Save Data and Create Package" and the package should be in `var/connect` directory.

Comment: this directory is empty, nothing saved in this directory. Even I checked var/pear directory too. It is also empty

Comment: Did you click exactly the button "Save Data and Create Package"? Does this folder have the necessary permissions - 777?

Comment: thanks, package is saved. Issue was with directory permissions